# SVG animation scaling while keeping the group from moving on one end

Tags: animation, svg

I am trying to use svg animation to get a dragonfly to flap its wings.

I am doing this by scaling the left and right wing on the x axis. the problem is when I scale it the wing moves. I want the left or right edge of the wing to stay in one spot when it scales.

here is the code for one wing

```
<g id="wing_left">
<g>
    <path fill="#88C9CE" d="M254.8,132.1c-66.2,6.7-130.7,21.1-193.3,47.2c-7.4,3.1-58.6,24.1-44.8,37.4
        c15.2,14.8,88.3,17.3,109.3,11.3C162.6,217.8,279.4,129.7,254.8,132.1z"/>
    <path fill="#92D9DE" d="M237.3,113.7c-16.1,3.6-245.9-31.8-250-22.3c-11.5,26.7,38.3,51.9,56.1,58.2
        c88.5,31.4,185.6,6.2,202.5-11.3C251.7,132.4,247.9,111.3,237.3,113.7z"/>
    <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M-1.2,97.7c9.1-4.5,84.8,7.2,83.7,7.1c-16.4-1.7-49.9-3.3-56.9-3.5c-32.2-1.2-24,7.4-22.5,11.8
        C5,118.4-7.2,100.6-1.2,97.7z"/>
    <path fill="#76B0B3" d="M249.3,145.5c-2.9,3-8,7.3-11.5,10.2c-21.1,17.5-102.1,8.9-102.1,8.9s54.5-2.2,86-13.4
        c13.2-4.7,21-10.2,23.2-12c0,0,1.1,1.4,2.1,2.5c1,1.1,2.3,1.8,2.3,1.8S249.3,145.5,249.3,145.5z"/>
</g>
<animateTransform id="wlFlapDown" attributeName="transform"
                  type="scale"
                  from="1 1" to="0.5 1"
                  begin="0s;wlFlapUp.end" dur="160ms"
                  repeatCount="indefinite"
                   fill="freeze"
        />
<animateTransform id="wlFlapUp" attributeName="transform"
                  type="scale"
                  from="0.5 1" to="1 1"
                  begin="wlFlapDown.end" dur="160ms"
                  repeatCount="indefinite"
                   fill="freeze"
        />
</g>
```

Here is the whole svg code or you can see it in [codepen](http://codepen.io/leohenning/pen/fFptk)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 18.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 viewBox="-14.4 7.7 550.5 426.8" enable-background="new -14.4 7.7 550.5 426.8" xml:space="preserve">
<g id="wing_left">
<g>
    <path fill="#88C9CE" d="M254.8,132.1c-66.2,6.7-130.7,21.1-193.3,47.2c-7.4,3.1-58.6,24.1-44.8,37.4
        c15.2,14.8,88.3,17.3,109.3,11.3C162.6,217.8,279.4,129.7,254.8,132.1z"/>
    <path fill="#92D9DE" d="M237.3,113.7c-16.1,3.6-245.9-31.8-250-22.3c-11.5,26.7,38.3,51.9,56.1,58.2
        c88.5,31.4,185.6,6.2,202.5-11.3C251.7,132.4,247.9,111.3,237.3,113.7z"/>
    <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M-1.2,97.7c9.1-4.5,84.8,7.2,83.7,7.1c-16.4-1.7-49.9-3.3-56.9-3.5c-32.2-1.2-24,7.4-22.5,11.8
        C5,118.4-7.2,100.6-1.2,97.7z"/>
    <path fill="#76B0B3" d="M249.3,145.5c-2.9,3-8,7.3-11.5,10.2c-21.1,17.5-102.1,8.9-102.1,8.9s54.5-2.2,86-13.4
        c13.2-4.7,21-10.2,23.2-12c0,0,1.1,1.4,2.1,2.5c1,1.1,2.3,1.8,2.3,1.8S249.3,145.5,249.3,145.5z"/>
</g>
<animateTransform id="wlFlapDown" attributeName="transform"
                  type="scale"
                  from="1 1" to="0.5 1"
                  begin="0s;wlFlapUp.end" dur="160ms"
                  repeatCount="indefinite"
                   fill="freeze"
        />
<animateTransform id="wlFlapUp" attributeName="transform"
                  type="scale"
                  from="0.5 1" to="1 1"
                  begin="wlFlapDown.end" dur="160ms"
                  repeatCount="indefinite"
                   fill="freeze"
        />
</g>
<g id="wing_right">
<g>
    <path fill="#88C9CE" d="M275.9,134c66.4,4.7,131.2,17.1,194.6,41.4c7.5,2.9,59.3,22.3,45.9,36.1c-14.8,15.2-87.7,19.9-109,14.6
        C370.6,216.9,251.2,132.2,275.9,134z"/>
    <path fill="#92D9DE" d="M285,113c16.2,3.1,244.8-39.1,249.2-29.7c12.3,26.3-36.8,53-54.4,59.8c-87.6,34-185.4,11.7-202.8-5.2
        C271.1,132.1,274.2,110.9,285,113z"/>
    <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M451.2,98.5c25.6-4.3,28.9-4.8,58.9-8.8c1.9-0.3,16.3-1.3,15.6,4.3c-0.2,1.4-6.5,17.8-6,13.2
        c0.1-0.8,0.9-9.8-1.3-12.5C513.9,88.7,445.7,99.5,451.2,98.5z"/>
    <path fill="#76B0B3" d="M291.3,155.4c21.9,16.6,99.9,5.4,99.9,5.4s-54.7-0.2-86.7-9.9c-13.4-4.1-22.5-9.1-24.1-10.3
        c0,0-0.8,0.9-1.8,1.6c0,0,0.1,2.2,0.1,2.2S287.6,152.7,291.3,155.4z"/>
</g>
<animateTransform id="wrFlapDown" attributeName="transform"
                  type="scale"
                  from="1 1" to="0.5 1"
                  begin="0s; wrFlapUp.end" dur="160ms"
                  repeatCount="indefinite"
                   fill="freeze"
        />
<animateTransform id="wrFlapDown" attributeName="transform"
                  type="scale"
                  from="0.5 1" to="1 1"
                  begin="wrFlapDown.end" dur="160ms"
                  repeatCount="indefinite"
                   fill="freeze"
        />
</g>
<g id="body" xmlns:inkpad="http://taptrix.com/inkpad/svg_extensions">
<g id="Layer_2" inkpad:layerName="body">
    <path fill="#D9AC32" d="M253.8,83.2c-4.5-29.5-6.4-53.2-16-74.7c-0.8-1.9-4.3,1-3.4,1.6c0.4,0.2,12.6,13.5,17.3,73.2
        C252.2,88.9,254.5,87.3,253.8,83.2z"/>
    <path fill="#D9AC32" d="M272.2,82.6c5.2-29.3,7.8-53,17.9-74.3c0.9-1.9,4.3,1.1,3.3,1.7c-0.4,0.2-12.9,13.2-19.1,72.7
        C273.7,88.2,271.5,86.6,272.2,82.6z"/>
    <path fill="#FFE008" d="M249.8,128.8l28.2-0.4c0,0,10.4,208,2.7,260.4c-10.3,71.1-18.9,49.7-27.9,0.4
        C243.4,337.1,249.8,128.8,249.8,128.8z"/>
    <path fill="#FFE008" d="M242.5,130.2c-0.2-12,9-21.8,20.6-22c11.5-0.2,21.1,9.4,21.2,21.4c0.2,12-9.7,17-21.2,17.2
        C251.5,146.9,242.7,142.2,242.5,130.2z"/>
    <path fill="#FFE008" d="M236.8,110.7c-0.3-18.4,12-32.8,26.5-33c14.5-0.2,25.8,13.9,26.1,32.2c0.3,18.4-11.7,25.1-26.3,25.3
        C248.6,135.4,237.1,129,236.8,110.7z"/>
</g>
<g id="Layer_3" inkpad:layerName="eyes">
    <g>
        <path fill="#F5F2E1" d="M227.8,95.9c-0.1-8.3,7.2-15.1,16.4-15.3c9.2-0.1,16.7,6.5,16.8,14.8c0.1,8.3-7.2,15.1-16.4,15.3
            C235.4,110.9,227.9,104.2,227.8,95.9z"/>
        <path d="M255.1,92c-0.6,1.6-7.3-5.5-19.7,3.7c-2.4,1.8-1.8-4.6-0.1-6C244.1,82.6,255.8,90.4,255.1,92z"/>
        <path fill="#D8E6C3" d="M228,96.2c-0.1-5.4,2.1,9.9,15.5,11.1c8.1,0.7,14.5-2.9,14.2-2.5c-3.9,4.4-9,5.5-10.5,5.7
            C236.8,111.8,228.2,106.5,228,96.2z"/>
    </g>
    <g>
        <path fill="#F5F2E1" d="M295.8,94.9c-0.1-8.3-7.7-14.9-16.8-14.8c-9.2,0.1-16.5,7-16.4,15.3c0.1,8.3,7.7,14.9,16.8,14.8
            C288.6,110.1,295.9,103.2,295.8,94.9z"/>
        <path d="M268.3,91.8c0.7,1.6,7.1-5.7,19.8,3.1c2.5,1.7,1.7-4.7-0.1-6C279.1,82.1,267.6,90.3,268.3,91.8z"/>
        <path fill="#D8E6C3" d="M295.5,95.2c-0.1-5.4-1.8,9.9-15.2,11.5c-8.1,1-14.6-2.5-14.3-2.1c4,4.3,9.2,5.2,10.7,5.4
            C287.2,111,295.7,105.5,295.5,95.2z"/>
    </g>
</g>
<path fill="#E5C907" d="M242.6,127.9c0-0.1,4.8,8.1,22.5,7.2c13.6-0.7,19-8.1,19-8.1c-0.4,4.9-11.3,11.2-18.3,11.6
    C260.3,139,247.3,137.3,242.6,127.9z"/>
<path fill="#E5C907" d="M249.3,143.6c0,0,6,3.9,15,3.2c10.4-0.8,14.4-4.7,14.4-4.6c0.2,4.1,0.5,8.3,0.4,8.6
    c-3.5,7.1-20.6,9.4-29.8,2C249,152.5,249.3,147.1,249.3,143.6z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that the origin for all scale transforms is at (0,0) which is at the top left of the SVG.  So your scale animations are centred on the left side of the SVG (x=0).

Basically you need to move the coordinate space for the wings, so that when the scale is applied, the wings are centred on x=0.

So the steps would be:

1. Use a translate transform to move your wings so they are centred at x=0
2. apply your scale animation in this coordinate space
3. surround that with a group with a transform that moves them back to their original position

For example:

```
<g id="wings" transform="translate(270,0)">
  <g>
    <g transform="translate(-270,0)">
      <g "left wing">
      <g "right wing">
    </g>
    <animateTransform .../>
  </g>
</g>
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/pe0fm8q2/)